# Is it possible to duplicate a MySQL table by simply copying the files and renaming them?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.5 in Windows. I have a database named "mydb" and the MySQL folder contains a subfolder named "mydb" too. The "mydb" database contains a table named "mytable", and the folder "mydb" contains the following files:

```
mytable.frm
mytable.MYD
mytable.MYI
```

Now, I want to duplicate the table into another table named "mychair".

Is it possible to copy the files above into another folder, rename them and then copy them back to the "mydb" folder in order to duplicate the table?
I tried to do that, changing the name of those files into "mychair.frm", "mychair.MYD" and "mychair.MYI" but it didn't work. However, after restarting the MySQL server, I could see and use that table into the mysql console, so it seems to be working.

I know, this is not the recommended way to do things. But I just want to know if this works and what the risks are of doing things this way.

Comment: On the surface I'd have to say no. There are system tables that have to be maintained and when you copy files like this; the system has no knowledge of the tables.  Why not just execute `create table myChair as (Select * from mytable)`  You'll have to add indexes and constraints afterwords but it should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for MyISAM tables with some precautions. If the server is either down or you have done `FLUSH TABLE` or `FLUSH TABLES` and can ensure no concurrent access (e.g with `LOCK TABLES`), a table can be copied on the file system level by copying the `.frm`, `.MYI`, and `.MYD` files. The same idea does not work with InnoDB tables, although it is possible to copy them individually outside of the SQL interface using special utilities, e.g with `xtrabackup`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good way to play with database files like this.

A good way is to do that via database query

```
insert into mytable
select * from mychair
```

This query will insert all of rows of `mychair` into `mytable` table provided the schema of both the tables is all same.

Comment: Depending upon the engine used, this could lock the entire `mychair` table during insertion, and you need to manually re-add all indices.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest just doing a mysqldump of the table (and data), then in the dump file rename the table to whatever you want, then create the table via the altered dumpfile.

Something like:

```
$ -> mysqldump -u<username> -p --opt --single-transaction <database_name> mychair > mychair.sql
# Edit mychair.sql to change mychair to mytable
$ -> mysql -u<username> -p -D <database_name> < mychair.sql
```

Comment: Which option did you go with?